# Testing the LinkedIn SDK Login

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, bitcode

I'm trying to test my linkedIn "log in" for my IOS app (using Swift)

I can't test this in the simulator because LinkedIn forces the user to open the LinkedIn app in order to sign up and LinkedIn isn't pre-installed in the simulator.

So, I figured, I would just test my app on my iPad instead.  However, in order to do this, Bitcode has to be disabled because the linkedIn SDK does not support this yet.

So, now I'm stuck how I can test LinkedIn Login. Any suggestion?

Comment: Disable bitcode. Is this a trick question?

Comment: When I run with the LinkedSDK, I get an error.  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).  I think I need to disable BITCODE from the "build phases" settings in order to run, but LinkedIn SDK doesn't support this yet.

Comment: Right. If the library doesn't support bitcode then you need to disable bitcode in your project.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but my issue is that I don't know how to test this on my phone because Apple requires that BITCODE be enabled.  I just want to test the code for now.  I can't use the simulator because it doesn't have the LinkedIn app installed.

Comment: Bitcode is not required. It's optional.

Comment: It used to be optional.  I think it's required now.  It's not letting me run outside the simulator with bitcode disabled

Comment: No, it's not required. I'm testing apps this very moment on real devices and the app has bitcode disabled.

Comment: Yes I can run it too, but not with the LinkedIn SDK.  If you are running with the LinkedIn SDK, can you tell me how you did that?